# Why doesn't Mexico take Gilead refugees?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-handmaids-tale

In *The Handmaid's Tale* it seems that Canada accepts refugees from Gilead, but there is no mention of Mexico doing so.  Doesn't Mexico border Gilead?  If so, why doesn't it help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mexico [doesn't border Gilead](https://the-handmaids-tale.fandom.com/wiki/Gilead#Map), according to a map shown in the Season 2 finale.

According to the map, Gilead occupies the northeastern United States, with "the colonies" to the west, and active warzones to the northwest and south.

Refugees from Gilead would have to cross active warzones to get to Mexico, whereas Canada has a direct border.

From https://the-handmaids-tale.fandom.com/wiki/Gilead#Map:

> The states that make up the Republic of Gilead in complete occupation are: Minnesota, Wisconsin, Illinois, Michigan, Indiana, Ohio, Tennessee, Kentucky, West Virginia, Virginia, North Carolina, Maryland, Pennsylvania, Delaware, New Jersey, New York, Connecticut, Rhode Island, Maine, New Hampshire, and Massachusetts.

The closest point to Mexico appears to be Kentucky, about 900 miles from Mexico's border.

Comment: I've not watched the show at all, is Gilead a reference to Stephen King's Dark tower series?

Comment: @GordonBennett It's not impossible, as The Gunslinger was published before the Handmaid novel.  I think it is more likely based on a Biblical reference, Hosea 6:8-  "Gilead is a city of those who work iniquity; it is stained with blood". And Gilead is the name of other places and people in the Bible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilead